# Sencha Touch 2.2 load store from JSON, data goes to raw column

Tags: json, sencha-touch-2, store

I'm trying to load a store from JSON received from webservices. But all the data from the JSON goes under the 'raw' column of the items in the store... 
I can't figure out why, my code seems correct. 
Any help is welcome.

My Model :

```
Ext.define('App.model.Node', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' }, 
            { name: 'version', type: 'int' }, 
            { name: 'user_id', type: 'int' }, 
            { name: 'tstamp', type: 'date' }, 
            { name: 'changeset_id', type: 'int' }, 
            { name: 'tags', type: 'string' }, 
            { name: 'geom', type: 'string'}
        ],

        idProperty: 'id'
    }
});
```

My Store :

```
Ext.define('App.store.NodeStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    xtype: 'nodestore',
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.proxy.Rest'
    ],
    config: {
        model: 'App.model.Node',
        storeId: 'nodeStore',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type:'rest',
            url:'http://localhost/server/nodes',
            reader: {
                type:'json',
                rootProperty: 'nodes'
            },
            noCache: false,
            limitParam: false,
            headers: {                
                'Accept' : 'application/json'                 
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My JSON :

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": "454467",
            "version": 6,
            "user_id": 52015,
            "tstamp": "2008-12-27 21:38:45",
            "changeset_id": "634766",
            "tags": "",
            "geom": "0101000020E6100000409CD1A0B29321405455682096804740"
        },
        {
            "id": "454468",
            "version": 8,
            "user_id": 52015,
            "tstamp": "2009-12-23 20:47:15",
            "changeset_id": "3437205",
            "tags": "",
            "geom": "0101000020E6100000357C0BEBC69321409EC02ACD9C804740"
        }, 
        {
            "id": "454469",
            "version": 7,
            "user_id": 52015,
            "tstamp": "2009-12-23 20:47:15",
            "changeset_id": "3437205",
            "tags": "",
            "geom": "0101000020E6100000347914F8D4932140B8BBBD5AA4804740"
        }
    ]
}
```

And when I do a

```
var nodeStore = Ext.getStore('nodeStore');
nodeStore.load();
console.log(nodeStore.getData());
```

we can see the following object, with my data in the raw column under items...

[image: Data in the store]

Comment: What's about the data standing in the "data" tag? Are there the same?

Comment: @LukasK. Yes, _data, data and raw are the same

Comment: Then you can ignore raw data i think. Raw data always show all the data load (by JSON in your case). In the raw data you can see the fields, which have been loaded. That are the fields defined in the model in addition to the fields not defined in the model. In your case they are the same, because you defined everything in the model.

Comment: @LukasK. I think I just figured it out... Look my answer below. Thanks! As you are here mayber you can answer my second question, do you know how to handle Many-to-Many relations in ST2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, my code is correct and the only thing missing is a callback in the load() function :

```
nodeStore.load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        console.log(records);
        console.log(nodeStore.getCount());
        nodeStore.each(function(element) {
            console.log(element.data.id);
        });
    },
    scope: this,
});
```

The problem was I was trying to access the store before it loaded the data. Now I'm waiting that all the data is loaded to access it, and it works.